# Darken When Hover For Button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, styled-components

I have a problem on darkening the button when hovering in my React app. The problem is that I'm using `linear-gradient` for its background color. The `darken` from `polished` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/polished) npm package works if I'm not declaring the background as `linear-gradient`

Pls see my code here

```
const AddButton= styled.button`
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary},
    ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary}
  );
 :hover, :active {
    background-color: ${(props) =>  props.theme.colors && darken(0.1, props.theme.colors.primary)};
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're darkening a colour and setting it as the background colour but it is covered up by the background image you are setting.

Create a new background image to replace the one you have instead.

```
:hover, :active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        ${(props) => darken(0.1, props.theme.colors.secondary)},
        ${(props) => darken(0.1, props.theme.colors.primary)}
    );
}
```